Cannot set the res.status to 404 and handle it in middle ware
Controller
const contact = await Contact.findById(req.params.id);
if (!contact) {
    res.status(404);
    throw new Error("Contact not Found");
}

res.status(200).json({ message: `Got contact with id: ${req.params.id}`, contact });

Middleware Error Handler
const { constants } = require("../constants");

const errorHandler = (err,req,res,next) => {
    const statusCode = res.statusCode ? res.statusCode : 500;
    console.log(res.statusCode)
    switch(statusCode) {
        case constants.VALIDATION_ERR: res.json({
            title: "Validation Failed",
            message: err.message,
            stackTrace: err.stack,
        });
        break;
        case constants.FORBIDDEN: res.json({
            title: "Forbidden",
            message: err.message,
            stackTrace: err.stack,
        });
        break;
        case constants.NOT_FOUND: res.json({
            title: "Not Found",
            message: err.message,
            stackTrace: err.stack,
        });
        break;
        case constants.UNAUTHORIZE: res.json({
            title: "warning ! Unauthorized",
            message: err.message,
            stackTrace: err.stack,
        });
        break;
        case constants.SERVER_ERR: res.json({
            title: "Server Error",
            message: err.message,
            stackTrace: err.stack,
        });
        break;
        default: 
        console.log("no Error, Everything is Good ")
        break;
    }
}

module.exports = errorHandler;


Main
const express = require("express");
const errorHandler = require("./middleware/errorHandler");
const connectDB = require("./config/dbConnection");
const dotenv = require("dotenv").config();

const app = express()

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

connectDB();

app.use(express.json())
app.use("/api/contacts", require("./routes/contactRoutes"))
app.use(errorHandler)

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
})

Constants are good and the middleware is used at last but I don't know why 404 is not passing to the middleware instead the 200 is passing.
I cannot Handle the not found status code. I have tried Everything but none works and I don't know why
I'm Expecting to handle the 404 for error in which the contact does not exists

Yeah, I figured out that the Mongoose is throwing an Error preventing to reach to the 404. After handling with the try catch block everything was solved.
My Solution might be the dumb one if anyone got better please post it so that i can learn.
const getContact = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    console.log("I'm get method of ID");
    try {
        const contact = await Contact.findById(req.params.id);
        console.log("this is contact: ", contact)
        if (!contact) {
            res.status(404);
            throw new Error("Contact not Found");
        }
        res.status(200).json({ message: `Got contact with id: ${req.params.id}`, contact });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404)
        throw new Error("Contact not Found");
    }
   
});


Hi, if you feel to improve this code, please see this. The code at present may hide the error object from a Mongoose error, it may be useful for troubleshooting. Therefore the statement in the catch block may be replaced with this next(error). This will propagate the error to Express, whatever it may be. Both errors - the custom error if there is no contact as well as the Mongoose error if any. Please add next to the async func as well.
